# Liferay - Title in Dynamic List Form Template

Tags: xml, forms, templates, liferay, title

Is it possible to make a title in the data Definitions from the Dynamic Data List Template?

For Example it should look like this:

```
TITEL1
text
boolean
radio
TITEL2
boolean
boolean
```

Any Souloutions out there?

Comment: Where should this title come from?

Comment: @TobiasLiefke, Thats my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the form template editor, you should see a *Paragraph* field type. Add that field above your `text` field.

Specify whatever heading text you want in the *Text* property. Do the same for the next heading you want to add.

Here's what the heading I added in the above manner looks like in the source XML view of the form template:

```
    <dynamic-element fieldNamespace="ddm" indexType="keyword" localizable="true" name="Heading_Text_Here" readOnly="false" repeatable="false" required="false" showLabel="true" type="ddm-paragraph" width="">
        <meta-data locale="en_US">
            <entry name="label">
                <![CDATA[Heading Text Here]]>
            </entry>
            <entry name="style">
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </entry>
        </meta-data>
    </dynamic-element>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what i meant

Comment: Glad to help. You should mark this as the answer then :)